# Where is Rails.application defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Out of curiosity, where is Rails.application defined? If I do this in irb in a Rails-powered app, I got an error:

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p327 :001 > require 'rails/application'
 => true 
1.9.3-p327 :002 > class App < Rails::Application; end
NoMethodError: undefined method `application' for Rails:Module
```

I have tried requiring more, like `active_support` and `rails/railtie/configuration` but no luck.

The purpose of this is to load a minimal Rails env where I can test an `ActiveRecord::Base` helper :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually when working with Rails you use `rails console` instead of IRB.  When you run `rails console` it will boot up your Rails application.

FWIW, Rails.application is defined in railties:
lib/rails.rb

Comment: I know. I am trying to load a minimal environment in a test. I have expanded my question with some context. Tnx!